# svg:image element is not always rendered/downloaded

Tags: image, firefox, svg

In the SVG file below, opened as a local file in firefox, the [first image](https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png) from IG is **not** displayed, while the [second image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/19/2016_Kodak_355_X_Instamatic_1.jpg/800px-2016_Kodak_355_X_Instamatic_1.jpg) from wikipedia is displayed.

I wonder why ? Is there any way to display the first image ?

Thanks.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="200">
  <image href="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/web/mobile_nav_type_logo.png/735145cfe0a4.png" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
  <image href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/19/2016_Kodak_355_X_Instamatic_1.jpg/800px-2016_Kodak_355_X_Instamatic_1.jpg" x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: They are both loaded for me (FF and Chrome on Win10).  I see no reason why they wouldn't be. Perhaps reset your browser cache, check adblocker settings etc.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thanks. unfortunately I don't see the first image on linux/FF 76.0.1  without adblocker+ cache empty. Furthermore, I can see the image in FF when I open it as a URL, without SVG.

Comment: Check the Network tab of your browser dev tools (press F12) and see what the HTTP result code is for that image file fetch.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I opened the SVG, with a new FF Profile and it works now. Thanks ! +1

Comment: @PaulLeBeau please post your comment as an answer so I can close my question :-)

Comment: That's okay. My comment wasn't really an answer.  It would probably make sense to post your own solution (new profile) as an answer, and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the "Facebook container" for firefox wich prevented FF to display the images from instagram.

Disactivating the plugin / Opening the SVG with a new profile fixed the problem.